# How can I activate a Service outside Activity correctly?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, repository-pattern, android-room

I am trying to build an app that will rely on a Webservice to work. To make it, I decided to follow the Model-View-ViewModel architecture together with the Repository pattern. I try to make this architecture inspired by the guidelines shown in [Guide to App architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#addendum), from Android Developer's Official Site.

I use OkHttp library to consume the WebService, and Room for the phone's database.

[image: Android's recommended architecture]

I made some testing to see if the app obtained succesfully the Data through the Webservice, from inside the Main Activity, and it worked; the App received successfully the Data.

```
ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        connected = false;
        Log.i("MainActivity", "MyWebService DISconnected successfully.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        myweb_service = ((MyWebService.LocalBinder)service).getService();
        connected = true;
        Log.i("MainActivity", "MyWebService connected successfully.");
    }
};

void doBindMyWebService() {
    if (bindService(new Intent(this, MyWebService.class),
            connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE))
    {
        mShouldUnbind = true;
    }
    else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "ERROR --> Service instance doesn't exist, or this Client doesn't have permission to access.");
    }
}

void doUnbindMyWebService() {
    if (mShouldUnbind) {
        unbindService(connection);
    }
}

doBindMyWebService();

/* I am not trying to extract this method at all; I just included it for
 * the sake of completeness
 */
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    doUnbindMyWebService();
}
```

Now, in order to stick to the chosen architecture, I am trying to move the code that creates the ServiceConnection in the Main Activity, outside the Activity, in order to decouple it from View logic. To do so, I tried wrapping the code that makes the ServiceConnection and binds it into a new class for handling Services. While extracting the code and tried to engage it with the Repository class, the next question came out: is it neccesary binding the Service in order to make it work, and retrieve data from it, or instead, I can do so without binding it at all? (For the record: this is not the question itself; I'm just pointing out what I was thinking while making the code)

Please notice that I am aware that I could just pass some context (the MainActivity's context or the Application context, for example) to the classes' constructors and store it in some property, but this is indeed what I am trying to avoid doing in order to prevent memory leaks. Long story short:

- The above code works within MainActivity
- I am trying to activate Services outside the Activity class, so I made a dedicated class to handle Services within it. I called this class "RemoteDataSource"
- I am trying to make the Repository class to retrieve the data from the Service, once the Service has completed the HTTP call and received the response.
- I want MyWebService to keep running, even if there isn't any Activity instanced.
- Trying to bind the Service to some context under these conditions seems pointless, because it might lead to memory leaks.
- It seems that calling onStartCommand isn't enough to make it run the Service.

Here's the code of MyWebService:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.myapp.model.MyDataModel;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MyWebService extends Service {
    private String url= "https://someserver.here/api/data/read.php";
    private String response = "";
    private JSONArray response_jsonarray;
    private boolean running = false;

    final static int MESSAGE = 1;

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return this.running;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        MyWebService getService() {
            return MyWebService.this;
        }
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        if (!running) return null;
        return this.response;
    }

    public JSONArray getResponseAsJsonArray() {
        if (!running) return null;
        return this.response_jsonarray;
    }

    public List<MyDataModel> getResponseAsObject() {
        if (!running) return null;

        ArrayList<MyDataModel> child_nodes = new ArrayList<MyDataModel>();

        for (int i = 0; i < this.response_jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject parent_obj = this.response_jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                long parent_id = parent_obj.getLong("id_parent");
                short type_id = (short)parent_obj.getInt("type");
                short status_id = (short)parent_obj.getInt("status_id");

                JSONObject childs_list = parent_obj.getJSONObject("childs");
                Iterator<String> iter_childs = childs_list.keys();
                while (iter_childs.hasNext()) {
                    JSONObject child_obj = childs_list.getJSONObject(iter_child.next());

                    long i_id = child_obj.getLong("id");
                    String i_name = child_obj.getString("name");
                    double i_lat = child_obj.getDouble("lat");
                    double i_long = child_obj.getDouble("long");
                    short i_order = (short)child_obj.getInt("order");

                    MyDataModel i_child = new MyDataModel(i_id, i_name, i_lat, i_long, 0, 0, type_id, status_id, 0, parent_id, i_order);
                    child_nodes.add(i_child);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return child_nodes;
    }

    /*
     * SERVICE LIFECYCLE
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i("MyWebService", "OnCreate TRIGGERED");

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.e("MyWebService", "ERROR --> " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                call.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.i("MyWebService", "GOOD -> Response received! :-)");

                final String myResponse = response.body().string();
                response = myResponse;
                try {
                    response_jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        this.running = true;

        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Log.i("MyWebService", "OnStartCommand TRIGGERED");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("MyWebService", "OnBind TRIGGERED");
        return mBinder;
    }
}
```

And here, the code of the class i called "RemoteDataSource":

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class RemoteDataSource {
    private boolean connected;
    private boolean mShouldUnbind;
    private MyWebService mWebService;

    private final int INTENT_WEBSERVICE = 1;

    public boolean isConnected() {
        return this.connected;
    }

    public boolean isBound() {
        return this.mShouldUnbind;
    }

    public ServiceConnection getConnection() {
        return this.connection;
    }

    private ServiceConnection connection;

    public MyWebService getMyWebService() {
        return this.mWebService;
    }

    public RemoteDataSource() {
        this.connection = new ServiceConnection() {

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                connected = false;
                Log.i("RemoteDataSource", "MyWebService DISconnected successfully");
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                mWebService = ((MyWebService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
                connected = true;
                Log.i("RemoteDataSource", "MyWebService connected successfully");
            }
        };
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        if (this.mWebService == null) return false;
        return this.mWebService.isRunning();
    }

    public void prepareWebService() {
        //TODO -> Consider this empty method as a symbol of what I am trying to achieve
    }

    public void startMyWebService() {
        this.mWebService.onStartCommand(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SYNC), 0, INTENT_WEBSERVICE);
    }

    public void stopMyWebService() {
        this.mWebService.stopSelf();
    }

    public void doBindMyWebService (Context context) {
        if (context.bindService(new Intent(context, MyWebService.class),
                this.connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)) {
            this.mShouldUnbind = true;
        } else {
            Log.e("RemoteDataSource", "ERROR --> Service instance doesn't exist, or this Client doesn't have permission to access.");
        }
    }

    public void doUnbindMyWebService (Context context) {
        if (this.mShouldUnbind) {
            context.unbindService(connection);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is some piece of my Repository class' constructor:

```
public Repository(Application application) {
    AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application);
    mParentDao = db.parentDao();
    mMyDataModelDao = db.myDataModelDao();

    mRemoteDataSource = new RemoteDataSource();

    /* XXX It was a bad idea, it gets stuck in an infinite loop; I just had to try anyway
     *     The point is, if I don't wait until MyWebService has made it's work,
     *       the app crashes with NullPointerException (or it seems so, at least)
     */
    while (!mRemoteDataSource.isRunning()) { continue; }

    mRemoteDataSource.startMyWebService();

    // [...]
}
```

My objective at this point is to handle this MyWebService of mine from the RemoteDataSource class, avoiding binding it to a context. The WebService might deserve a dedicated Thread, but I am still a noob with threads; so i'd rather keep it simple until I see it working; later I will worry about improving performance.

In any case, I think I am too confused about how should I start the Service (please notice that I am not too familiar with Services and the way to handle them). Is the way I tried to handle the service wrong? If it is, what am I overlooking? What should I have in mind in order to de-couple MyWebService from the View logic?

Comment: Do you want a Service for what exactly? Sorry but i am a bit confused about what do you want exactly

Comment: The WebService (a subclass of mine extending Service) retrieves data from a server in order to display it. Following some examples I found, I successfully retrieved the data creating the ServiceConnection in MainActivity as explained above. Now I am trying to refactor: in other words: de-coupling the WebService handling from Activity, and handle it from a dedicated class instead (a class that I named RemoteDataSource)

Comment: At the same time, I tried to build the architecture using [this codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view) as a guide to implement Room with the ViewModel pattern.

Comment: Hello Sebas. I have  a repository with MVVM, LiveData, Room and Dagger. I hope this code helps you. Is similar that the architecture you mentioned above.https://github.com/Surkhojb/NewsApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/clean/juanjo/newsapp/data

Comment: @Juanjo Berenguer Thank you very much. I will check it out. It might be useful to see how should I manage the Service in this kind of architecture.

Comment: I dont run a Service. I just have the different datasources ( local and remote ) and the repository manage it. And in the application class i inject this modules and i have acces from every activity or fragment from the app. I think you are a bit confused with the picture. webService is not a service created in the app is just a Cloud server that provide an API_Rest to be consumed.

Comment: Perhaps I am confused, but the motive i named the Service as WebService is because it uses OkHttp to retrieve the data in JSON format. (Isn't that what is REST about?) For now I don't see the advantages of using Retrofit, so for now I'd rather don't use it. The main motive for this is that I am trying to use as few third-parties libraries as possible.

I will have to take my time to study your repository, and think deeply about all this...

Comment: I understand that using third-parties libraries can be a mess sometimes but in the case of Retrofit is really really good. I recomend this library to handle Rest apis. Is powerfull an very easy to use. If you have some doubts you can send me a message to my email.

Comment: @Juanjo Berenguer I must apologize; when posting the relevant code to provide the minimal example, I renamed the variables, methods and classes to make them more understandable in some way, for the context of the question; I left some of them unrenamed, which breaks the [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I was trying to provide. Even through I reviewed it several times, both before and after posting, and I didn't notice it until now, it's still my fault; I am so sorry for the inconvenience. I corrected the renaming mistakes I have seen right away.

Comment: While trying to figure out an answer for this question, I ended up making [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52442384/3692177), which is related to this one.