# How can I make some class, running in the Main Thread, await concurrently for other class to reach some specific state?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, okhttp, android-room

I am having serious difficulties to understand how can I make some AsyncTask children, declared and instantiated in the Main Thread, to await for a Service child instance to reach some specific state.

As code examples here is the relevant part for Service; this code does what expected: receives the JSON response and holds it.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private boolean received = false;
    private string url = "http://someserver.mine/get-data-in-json-format";

    // [...]
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        doHttpJsonQuery();
    }

    public boolean responseReceived() {
        return this.received;
    }

    public List<MyModel> getResponseAsObject() {
        if (!this.received) return new ArrayList<MyModel>;

        // Many code lines that convert the data into a list.
        // [...]

        return the_list;
    }

    // [...]
    private void doHttpJsonQuery() {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                call.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                final String myResponse = response.body().string();
                //...and some code to hold data as JSONArray
                //[...]
            }
        });
        this.received = true;
    }
}
```

This Service works; fine. Then, from another class (which purpose will be to handle persistence inserting the received data in a local Room Database), I try to do the following (here's where my mind is blown):

```
public class DataRepository {
    private MyRoomDatabase db;
    private MyModelDao mModelDao;
    // I'm skipping irrelevant code on purpose
    // [...]

    public DataRepository(Application application) {
        db = MyRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        mModelDao = db.myModelDao();
        // [...]

        //  Here I instance a subclass of ContextWrapper(i named it RemoteDataSource) which
        // responsability will be handling different Services for making HTTP operations
        mRemoteDataSource = new RemoteDataSource(application.getApplicationContext());
        // It holds a reference to MyService. It has some public methods, like this one, to
        // control the referenced Service from outside with some encaspsulation
        mRemoteDataSource.startMyService();

        // Instantiating a private nested class...
        PopulateDbAsync mPopulateDbAsync = new PopulateDbAsync(db);
        mPopulateDbAsync.doInBackground();
    }
    // [...]

    // Here is the failing code
    private class PopulateDbAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        PopulateDbAsync(MyRoomDatabase db) {}

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
            MyService mService = mRemoteDataSource.getMyService();
            if (mService == null) {
                // This doesn't happen at all right now...
                Log.e("MY_ERROR","DataRepository.PopulateDbAsync --> MyService from RemoteDataSource is NULL!!!!");
            }
            List<MyModel> the_list = mService.getResponseAsObject();
            if (the_list == null) {
                // HERE! I obtain the NullReferenceException here.
                // I am confused about how would I avoid this flaw in my code
                Log.e("MY_ERROR", "DataRepository.PopulateDbAsync --> error: response isn't ready yet.");
            }
            for (MyModel i_model : the_list) {
                Log.d("MY_LOG", "DataRepository.PopulateDbAsync --> Inserting data in local DB...");
                mModelDao.insert(i_model);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Summarizing: my problem is that I will always get `NullReferenceException` in this line:

```
for (MyModel i_model : the_list) {
```

I am not familiar with multithreading, asyncronous operations and concurrent execution. I have been reading, for two   weeks, lots of different documents on the Internet both from Android Official Website and from other websites as well, trying to figure it out... "AsyncTask is not good to perform this kind of operations"... so, what infrastructure should I implement, I have been wondering... should I use Handlers, Threads, Messengers, or what? The more I read, the more confused I get. It's like I have an [Analysis Paralysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis) issue...

Most of the examples I find out there provide too verbose code examples on how to implement multithreading and concurrent execution; while I read them and try to figure out how to implement those structures in my code, I just get stuck; also, with so many classes to choose, I get even more confused...

Due to the HTTP call will need to be performed asyncronously (and response time will not always be   the same), I am trying to figure out how to make the piece of code that throws the `NullReferenceException` "wait" for MyService to complete it's job before starting it's execution; `while` loops will not work due to it would break Main Thread's lifecycle. "Knowing" if the Service completed it's task or not would be as simple as using the boolean method `responseReceived`. The big idea is, every time new data is obtained through HTTP, updating the RoomDatabase with it, and, meanwhile, MainActivity would be showing the current local data (if any, or an empty list if there's nothing yet).

So, when I get it, I will understand how to refactor the whole code structure properly to start adding more `Service` child instances into my `RemoteDataSource` class, which I created with the idea of having all Service childs that will use `OkHttp` to perform HTTP communications, wrapped together in a single class for better organization.

What would be the proper way to achieve what I am looking for about this? Would someone be able to provide some short example explaining the code structure I will need for something like this? Examples with empty blocks containing comments like "code to execute when ready here" would be great so I can figure it out.

The question exposed here is related with the same project that made me post [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52202101/3692177) some weeks ago; I have been reading here and there, performing some trial-and-error and correcting some code issues here-and-there since then; however, I am making a different question here; finding an answer for this would probably be the first step towards figuring out an answer to the other question as well.

### URL References to documentation I have been reading

Some of the documentation I have been reading (but not limited to):

- [AsyncTask class documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)
- [Handler class documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler)
- [Basics on Multithreading](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/multithreading-in-android)
- [Introduction to background processing in Android - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)
- [Thread With Handlers - Android Example](https://androidexample.com/Thread_With_Handlers_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=58&aaid=83)
- [Messenger class documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger)

Comment: When I have somemore time, I will try to compile the different websites I have been reading to understand how to deal with this problem, and post their links in a question update as a reference.

Comment: As I understand, what you are really trying is to achieve a synchronous work flow using asynchronous threads. That's the basic problem. Is it? correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Perhaps my code implementation is even more wrong that I thought; some of the code blocks I used are copy-pasted-adapted after reading about them, so I tried to implement them to see if they work as expected; as I said earlier, I am trully confused about AsyncTasks, multithreading and otehr stuff. I will review my browser's history to compile the websites I read, markers, and other means I used to keep URL references; when I have it, I will provide them in a question update, to give somemore context to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Well problem is with your application logic as follows,

If you are using `AsyncTask` that is obviously a separate thread from the main thread. But syncing to your database after retrieving data via HTTP call is a process which has a sequence ( Call through HTTP and retreive -> then persist to database ), it cannot perform asynchronously. So when you call,

```
List<MyModel> the_list = mService.getResponseAsObject();
```

this call happens in a particular thread and the program flow is in a different thread.
Since these are asynchronous tasks, they work asynchronously. which means you will never know which one will execute first and which one is next. But as per your logic,

```
if (the_list == null) {
```

this part essentially need `the_list` to be initialized to run. But the problem is at that point, service thread has not finished his work to perform your next logic. so its obvious breaking.

Better if you can re-design this so that you wait for the HTTP request to complete and then persist to database. Because suppose if your HTTP request complets first but still it returns you `null` or whatever not-desired output. So in that case you need to handle it in your logic.

OK so let me tell you a quick workaround.
Lets use just one thread instead of different threads. So consider changing following line

```
private class PopulateDbAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
```

to

```
private class PopulateDbAsync
```

then you will get an error with

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
```

since we no longer extend AsyncTask class.

so change it as follows, by removing `@Override`

```
public Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
```

This should fix the stated problem here.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. As I stated in the my question, I am aware that I get `NullReference` exception due to a syncronization issue between threads. I also said I am not familiar with multi-threading, that is why I am confused about what actions to take in order to "workaround" this problem. I have provided reference to some documentation I have been reading, perhaps it will help to understand the kind of confusion I have right now, or how did I come to this "code mess"

Comment: After all, due to I am not familiar with multi-threading, the code I posted here is the result of copy->paste->adapt->createlogs->trial_and_error in order to figure out how to make is work as expected. But the code examples I found are so verbose and complicated, that I am having difficulties to figure out how should I implement them in my case. Anyway, I am grateful for your help.

Comment: So, you mean I should pefmorm the Database Population in a Syncronous way while waiting for Asyncronous HTTP calls to finish? I don't get it. (commented before your update, for the record)

Comment: I edited my answer with a quick workaround. please check.

Comment: Ok. I don't get it yet, but I will make the change to see what happens...

Comment: what I did was making the process synchronous

Comment: Well, that fixed the Exception, thank you. Now I am having a different issue, related to some dirty workaround I performed in RemoteDataSource's `startMyService` method --> `if (this.my_service == null) this.my_service = new MyService()`... somehow I have the feeling that it was a dirty hack... perhaps Services are supposed to be instantiated in a different way? I will adapt my question in three days to provide some context about this... or perhaps I should open a new question about this other issue, I am not sure...

Comment: If my answer was helpful to overcome what you were experiencing, could you please accept the answer and may be add informative question as an edit to this about your second problem. will try my best to help :)

Comment: It was helpful, but the main question remains, because I want `PopulateDbAsync.doInBackground()` to start executing when `MyService.responseReceived() == true`... because of that, I think it is still too soon to accept an answer.

Comment: This won't be useful at all; if I don't make the `PopulateDbAsync` inner class a child of `AsyncTask`, I would get `IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.`. I know because I have made a similar class to test a dummy `INSERT` directly; so this answer is not useful at all. I'm sorry.

Comment: actually what you are asking is a very broad topic which really cannot explain all here I guess. I recommend you to read and see about how multi-threading should be used and how and why its used when it comes to REST and DB technologies.

Comment: This question is 3 years old already (the problem I was solving here is not my problem anymore, *but this question is still useful*  –at least for me it is). That said, I want to mantain this question, and, perhaps, improve it. I don't know if you noticed I self-answered it. I'd like you to check my self-answer, and I'd appreciate if you left a comment on it to know if you think my solution is good or is rather a hack. Your answer has very complete information that's for sure, am I am grateful for that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: [creating custom listeners](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners).

### Steps to create a custom listener

**1. Define an interface** as an event contract with methods that define
    events and arguments which are relevant event data.

**2. Setup a listener member variable and setter in the child object** which can be assigned an implementation of the interface.

**3. Owner passes in a listener** which implements the interface and handles the events from the child object.

**4. Trigger events on the defined listener** when the object wants to communicate events to it's owner

---

I got the `NullReferenceException` because `MyService` didn't finish it's job yet. So, first I create the listener's structure within `MyService` class like this (steps 1 and 2):

```
private MyServiceListener listener;

public interface MyServiceListener {
    public void onDataDownloaded();
}

public void setMyServiceListener(MyServiceListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

And, within the HTTP request's callback (step 4):

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
    final String myResponse = response.body().string();
    //...and some code to hold data as JSONArray
    //[...]

    // XXX Trigger the custom event
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onDataDownloaded();
    }
}
```

Now, I just can wrap the code that triggered the `NullReferenceException` within the custom listener like this (step 3):

```
// Within DataRepository class
mService.setMyServiceListener(new MyService.MyServiceListener) {
    @Override
    public void onDataDownloaded() {
        List<MyModel> the_list = mService.getResponseAsObject();
        if (the_list == null) {
            // HERE! I obtainED the NullReferenceException here.
            Log.e("MY_ERROR", "DataRepository.PopulateDbAsync --> error: response isn't ready yet.");
        }
        for (MyModel i_model : the_list) {
            Log.d("MY_LOG", "DataRepository.PopulateDbAsync --> Inserting data in local DB...");
            mModelDao.insert(i_model);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Actually, the real implementation required to nest this code example into another custom listener following similar steps; but this worked for me.

Comment: However, I am terrible summarizing things... perhaps, someday, I'll end up editing the question to summarize the main point...